# Rails 3 Custom Domains A Record vs CNAME

Tags: dns

Could someone explain the difference between an A Record and a CNAME, and what I should be telling my users to do if I am building a site that allows for custom domains to point to a subdomain on my hosted service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A record... www.rabbot.com -> 123.123.123.123 (ie. an actual IP address)
CNAME record... www.philip.com -> www.rabbot.com (ie. more like an alias)

Your life will be much simpler if you have your users to use a CNAME as they can point their domains to yours.  Then if you need to update your server's IP address you can simply update the single A record you have instead of making all your users update their DNS entries.

This is true regardless of what web framework you are using...